# Timestamp on x-axis in timeseries ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, timestamp, time-series

I have measurement data from the past months:

[image]

Variables

```
 x <- df$DatoTid
 y <- df$Partikler
 color <- df$Opgave
```

I'm trying to plot my data based on the timestamp, so that I have the hours of the day in the x-axis, instead of the specific POSIXct datetime.
I would like the labels and ticks of the x-axis to be fx "00:00", "01:00",..."24:00".
So that noon is in the middle of the x-axis.

So far I tried to convert the datetime values into characters. 
Doesn't look good yet (as you can see the axis ticks and labels are gone. Possibly other things are wrong as well).

Can someone help me? 
And please let me know how to upload the data for you. I don't know how to add a huge .csv-file....

[image]

```
# Rounding up to nearest 10 min: 
head(df)
df$Tid2 <- format(strptime("1970-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d", tz="CET") + 
round(as.numeric(df$DatoTid)/300)*300 + 3600, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
head(df)
df$Tid2 <- as.character(df$Tid2)
str(df)

x <- df$Tid2
y <- df$Partikler
color <- df$Opgave

plot2 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) +
  geom_point(shape=16, alpha=0.6, size=1.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("00:00:00", "06:00:00", "09:00:00", "12:00:00", "18:00:00", "21:00:00")) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Case") +
  xlab(" ") +
  ylab(expression(paste("Partikelkoncentration [pt/cc]"))) +
  myTheme + 
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=8), legend.title=element_text(size=8))
plot2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by making a new time stamp that uses a single day, but the hours/minutes/seconds of your existing time stamp.

First, here's a made-up version of your data, here using a linear trend in `Partikler`:

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)
df <- data_frame(Tid2 = seq.POSIXt(from = ymd_h(2019010100), 
                                   to = ymd_h(2019011500), by = 60*60),
                 Partikler = seq(from = 0, to = 2.5E5, along.with = Tid2),
                 Opgave = as.factor(floor_date(Tid2, "3 days")))

# Here's a plot that's structurally similar to yours:
ggplot(df, aes(Tid2, Partikler, col = Opgave)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Case")
```

[image]

Now, if we change the timestamps to be in the same day, we can control them like usual in ggplot, but with them collapsed into a single day of timing. We can also change the x axis so it doesn't mention the date component of the time stamp:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Tid2_sameday = ymd_hms(paste(Sys.Date(), 
                                      hour(Tid2), minute(Tid2), second(Tid2))))


ggplot(df2, aes(Tid2_sameday, Partikler, col = Opgave)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Case")  +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

[image]